# How do I get PySpark to write intermediate results to disk before running out of memory?

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

**Background**:  In Hadoop Streaming, each reduce job writes to the hdfs as it finishes, thus clearing the way for the Hadoop cluster to execute the next reduce.

I am having trouble mapping this paradigm to (Py)Spark.

As an example,

```
df = spark.read.load('path')
df.rdd.reduceByKey(my_func).toDF().write.save('output_path')
```

When I run this, the cluster collects all of the data in the dataframe before it writes anything to disk.  At least this is what it looks like is happening as I watch the job progress.

My problem is that my data is much bigger than my cluster memory, so I run out of memory before any data is written.  In Hadoop Streaming, we don't have this problem because the output data is streamed to the disk to make room for the subsequent batches of data.

I have considered something like this:

```
for i in range(100):
    (df.filter(df.loop_index==i)
        .rdd
        .reduceByKey(my_func)
        .toDF()
        .write.mode('append')
        .save('output_path'))
```

where I only process a subset of my data in each iteration.  But this seems kludgy mainly because I have to either persist `df`, which isn't possible because of memory constraints, or I have to re-read from the input hdfs source in each iteration.

One way to make the loop work is to partition the source folders by day or some other subset of the data.  But for the sake of the question, let's assume that isn't possible.

**Questions**: How do I run a job like this in PySpark?  Do I just have to have a much bigger cluster?  If so, what are the common practices for sizing a cluster before processing the data?

Comment: Did you try to set spark.rdd.compress=true ?

Comment: No, would that help?  Unless that make spark write to hdfs, that doesn't solve my problem.  Compressing the rdd might make a bit more data fit in memory, but that doesn't solve the root issue that I am asking about.

Comment: Since there is no hint what `my_func` does it is hard to say definitely where is the problem. Also you should always provide `schema` when converting to a `DataFrame` if need decent performance.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to repartition your data in a large number of partitions. The example below would be similar to your for loop, although you may want to try with less partitions first

```
df = spark.read.load('path').repartition(100)
```

You should also review the number of executors you are currently using (`--num-executors`). Reducing this number should also reduce your memory footprint.